# Dynamic Parameter Query in Power Query Advanced Editor

Tags: excel, validation, parameters, powerquery

Currently I am struggling with the following task.

I added Parameters into my excel list to just load a part of my data that contain the following parameters:

Parameter1 = Value

Parameter2 = Value

Parameter3 = Period of time

and added them into the advanced editor of Power Query:

#"Filtered Row" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Typ",  each ([Column1] = **Parameter1**)),

#"Filtered Row1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Row", each ([Column2] = **Parameter2**)),

#"Filtered Row2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Row1", each ([Column]= **Parameter3**)),

This works fine for me.
However, it would be nice to add following things:

Range of Values for Parameter 3, so that instead of only to be able to load just one period of data to load multiple or ranges of periods.

If i choose to let one parameter blank that it will automatically load the whole data of the parameter, as if i would have not chosen to use this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple values, *Parameters* perhaps aren't the most suitable option. I would prefer to store my list of values within another query.

For example, assuming that other query is named *Parameter1List* and comprises a single-column table with header *Parameter1*:

```
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(
        #"Changed Type", 
        each 
            if Parameter1List[Parameter1]{0} = null then
                true
            else
                List.Contains(Parameter1List[Parameter1], [Column1])
    )
```

The `if` statement checks whether the first entry in *Parameter1List* is empty: if so, all rows are returned; otherwise, Column1 is filtered according to the entries in *Parameter1List*.

Comment: I always used something similar to https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2018/05/30/creating-dynamic-parameters-in-power-query/

Comment: @horseyride Thanks - looks interesting, will check it out.